# Celery : Create only one queue per each concurrent worker

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a flask application with two celery tasks. It is a user-based scraping job. So user give the CSV urls and based on that we do scraping for each user.

My Code is like follows:

```
@celery.task(bind=True,queue="imageScraping")
def saveUrlData(self,id, imgs,outputDir, isLast = False):
    #Save Image Data From URL to Directory and Insert Record in DB

@celery.task(bind=True, queue="pageScraping")
def startScraping(self,usrReqId,filename):
    #Do Page Scraping and parsing the data. Then pass it that to saveUrlData()

@app.route('/sendRequest', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    # User file receive. Store its information and calling startScraping()
```

I need to maintain a sequence in `saveUrlData()` for each user. So I only require one queue per user. I am starting celery from following commands.

```
celery -A app.celery worker --concurrency 1 -Q imageScraping

celery -A app.celery worker --concurrency 10 -Q pageScraping
```

I am using concurrency so I can pageScraping queue for multiple user. But for imageScraping if I use `--concurrency 1` then both user's queues mixedup. If I use `--concurrency 10` then a single user's queue is not maintained.

**So basically I need an imgScraping queue for each pageScraping worker to maintain queue**

Comment: I would rather move that logic to Flask, so it manages how many tasks of each type are sent to Celery for processing...